# Tehillim for segulot

Tags: tehilim-psalms, segulah, avodath-hashem

I'm trying to write a master list of all tehillim to read for various segulot, excluding shimusha tehillim. I've compiled the following, but I'm curious if there are any more:
(also I can't figure out to make footnotes without links so I can cite the sources):

- An intimate plea for Hashem's guidance - 16, 19, 139;
- Shidduch - 32, 38, 70, 71, 72, 82, 121, 124;
- On the day of a wedding - 19 (per Chabad, the kallah recites all tehillim)(per Ashkenaz, 128 under chuppah);
- For barren woman - 102, 103;
- For healthy childbirth - 4, 5, 20, 35, 57, 93, 108, 142;
- For a woman in difficult labor - 100;
- Upon the birth of a child - 20, 139;
- On the day of a bris mila - 12;
- For one's success learning Torah - 119;
- Corresponding to age - if 13, one says 14;
- For rain - 17, 25, 32, 86, 103, 105, 108, 120, 121, 123, 124, 130, 136, followed by a special Yehi Ratzon;
- For livelihood - 23, 24, 36, 62, 65, 85, 104, 121, 136, 144, 145;
- For peace - 46;
- Shalom Bayis - Spell out שלום הבית with 119 everyday;
- For success - 57, 112, 122;
- At the dedication of a monument - 1
- For parnassa - Any three chapters of Tehillim, specifically after davening;
- Eliminate sleep - Shir Hamalos (120-134);
- When traveling on a journey - 91;
- Against haters - 71;
- Antidote for rejoicing at an enemies downfall - 7;
- Protection against ayin hara - 59;
- Weapon against yetzer hara - reciting sefer tehillim three times in one day;
- The ability to walk away from anger, or evil talk - entire 150 tehillim;
- For the Jewish people - 43, 79, 80, 83, 130, 142;
- Victory - 12;
- For gratitude/thanksgiving - 9, 21, 57, 95, 100, 116, 138;
- Thanksgiving for a miracle - 18;
- Thanksgiving for being rescued - 124;
- For release of prisoners - 142;
- For supernatural results - 121, 130, or 142;
- All ailments (including acute depression) and difficult situations in a person's life - 16, 32, 41, 42, 59, 77, 90, 105, 137, 150;
- For recovery from illness - 6, 13, 20, 22, 23, 30, 32, 38, 41, 51, 86, 88, 91, 102, 103, 121, 130, 142, 143 (spell out name from 119);
- In a house of mourning - 49;
- At a graveside or Yahrtzeit - 16, 17, 33, 72, 91, 104, 130 (spell out name from 119);
- In times of crises - 20, 121, 130;
- For help in troublesome times - [16], 21, [25], [26], 38, [54], [81], 85, 86, [87], 102, 130, 142;
- Rescue from enemies - 125 seven times;
- For a dybbuk - at least 91 or 10, 91, 127 and the patient recites 20, 90, and Ana B’koach;
- When Eretz Yisrael is in danger - 83, 130, 142;
- For harsh decrees, that the nations decree on Yisrael - 62;
- To awaken the merits of our ancestors - 16;
- Tikun HaKlalit - 16, 32, 41, 42, 59, 77, 90, 105, 137, 150;
- Atonement from sins - 150 twice;
- For repentence - 51 and/or 90;
- Sweeten harsh judgments - 39, 77;
- For a favorable judgment - 7, 35, 93;
- Like a fast - reciting Sefer Tehillim 3 times in one day;
- Keeping out of Gehinnom - 25;
- To rectify all personal flaws and will be guaranteed a place in Olam HaBo - memorize the entire Tehillim;
- To be worthy of Olam HaBo - recite the entire Tehillim daily;
- Beis Olam - 16, 17, 28, 33, 34, 4th book, 91, 104, 111, 112, 119-38, 145-50.

I left out the tehillim schedules and the tehillim for specific days. Am I missing anything? I have sources but I can't figure out footnotes without links.

Comment: Why can't you copy sources without links?

Comment: What's the source code for footnotes or endnotes?

Comment: Segulah for learning a book in Tanakh: 1-150

Comment: It should be noted that different communities have rather significant variations in which tehillim should be recited for which purpose.

Comment: I have copious footnotes explaining that.

Comment: You can write footnotes using the [code for superscripts and subscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196995/210480), but in this case since you have so many lines I would just use parentheses at the end of each line

Comment: Some of the footnotes are two paragraphs long, so it's just going to muddy up the list.

Comment: https://www.psalmsonline.org/psalms-for-special-occasions There's a lot here.